# Do in need to add ('s') at last of variable name to create an Array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var names = ["pracas" , "prakash", "ramesh"];
document.getElementById("myh").innerHTML = names[1];
```

OUTPUT>> prakash

```
var name = ["pracas" , "prakash", "ramesh"];
document.getElementById("myh").innerHTML = name[1];
```

Output is >> r

Answer (score 0):

No, you just have to make sure that the variable does not exist already. `window.name` does exist already, and your assignment collides with that. `name =` actually calls a setter, which casts the array to a string, and therefore you get the second strings character with `name[1]`.

```
  window.name = ["a", "b"];
  console.log(window.name); // "a,b"
```